# Date Index - Long Range Search All Rows, Small Not

Tags: mysql, indexing, date-range

**Why MySQL search all rows when I switch to a 1 year range?**

```
--Table dates  
id (int)   
date (timestamp)  
value (varchar)  

PRIMARY(id), date_index(date)
```

**1750 rows**

Executing
`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM dates WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-04-27' AND '2011-04-28'`

The **rows** column display **18 rows**.
If I increase or decrease the BETWEEN range - 1 year for example - the **rows** column display **1750 rows**.

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM dates WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-04-27' AND '2012-04-28'`
`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM dates WHERE date BETWEEN '2010-04-27' AND '2011-04-28'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer builds the query plan depending on several things including the amount/distribution of the data. My best guess would be that you don't have much more than a year's data or that using the index for the year's worth of data wouldn't use many less rows than the total table size.

If that doesn't sound right can you post up the output of:

```
SELECT MIN(date), MAX(date) FROM dates;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dates WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-04-27' AND '2012-04-28';
```

This article I wrote shows some examples of how the optimizer works too: [What makes a good MySQL index? Part 2: Cardinality](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/what-makes-a-good-mysql-index-part-2-cardinality/)

Comment: It's the "Why isn’t MySQL using my index?" section that's most relevant

Comment: Nice article. Definitely I have to dig more on this subject. This matter isn't trivial. Thanks James